# How can I fix a wrinkle?

Tags: modeling

I did this image from a plane and fill it in.

[image]

I didn't do it well so when I fill it in I have a wrinkle.

[image]

I tried to fix it with Sculpt mode but I can't. I saw an answer from here. I tried to fix it with Physics but nothing.

Can someone help me? Thanks

[image]

[image]

[Blend File Download](http://http:/Ratoncito%20dulce%20super%20chulo5.blend)

[Blend File Download](http:///Users/meriandrobbie/Dropbox/Meri/NEW%20ARTISTIC%20CARDS/Ratoncito%20dulce%20super%20chulo5.blend)

Comment: There are some topology issues which won't be corrected neither with sculpting nor boolean modifier nor marking edges as sharp. Please [upload your file on the blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and edit your question / add a comment with the resulting link; this will allow to look at your file

Comment: You have a mix of several problems: non planar geometry, overlapping vertices and a large n-gon not subdividing properly due to the first and second issues.  Having a large face with more than 4 vertices to cover all of that surface is not a good idea in this case.

Comment: I found a hidden mickey

Answer (score 1):

After filling you might want to triangulate faces <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>). Fix the topology by moving vertices. Then you can dissolve unwanted faces (press <kbd>Space</kbd>, write *dissolve*, select "dissolve faces").

Another way (the easier and faster way) is to build an extra cube, and with the boolean modifier, you perfectly cut the face of your model by the face of that extra cube.

To fix the current topology, you might also try to "mark sharp" some of the edges, and or, to bevel or create extra loopcuts near areas you want to be sharper. That way the subdivision modifier won't round up as much on those areas.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I don't want to cut the entire face just some edges that are not vertex or faces. You can see it above. What can I do?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I got (above)  I shouldn't do it well I think. Thanks again.

Comment: can you provide the blend file? I'll see what I can do

Comment: Thanks a lot,  the file is  : Ratoncito dulce super chulo5.blend

Comment: you have to upload the Blend file to somewhere and provide the link, so I can do the download

Comment: under Dropbox, you have to create a "share link", then share it here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47384/discussion-between-meri-and-mcunha).